# If $f(2\alpha-\theta) = f(\theta)$, then $\theta=\alpha$ is a line of symmetry of $r=f(\theta)$. How do you derive $f(2\alpha-\theta) = f(\theta)$?

Tags: intuition, polar-coordinates

For Polar Coordinates I know that for **x-axis symmetry** $f(-\theta)=f(\theta)$,

for **y-axis symmetry** $f(\theta)=f(\pi-\theta)$,

and for **symmetry about the origin** $f(\theta)=f(\theta+\pi)$.

The big question however, is given the above information or otherwise, how do you get to $f(2\alpha-\theta) = f(\theta)$?

Thanks in advance.
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a polar function $f$ to have radial line of symmetry $\theta = \alpha$, we must have $f(\alpha - \phi) = f(\alpha + \phi)$ for all  $\phi$.  Now, put $\phi = \theta - \alpha$ to obtain the equation
$$
f(2\alpha - \theta) = f(\theta)
$$
for all $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just need to understand where the $f(\alpha - \phi) = f(\alpha + \phi)$ comes from? regards.

Comment: That's what mirror symmetry means!  Whatever the function gives measuring $\phi$ away from $\alpha$ in one direction, it gives the same value measuring $\phi$ away from $\alpha$ in the other direction.  The ray in the direction of angle $\alpha$ is the axis of this symmetry (where $\phi = 0$).